# Subdocuments mongoose returns [object]

Tags: express, mongoose

Subdocuments returned as [object] instead of value

Im trying to retrieve values from a subdocument. But the subdocuments are returned as [object]. I have read a couple of threads about this and tried the code solution below, which still gives me [object] instead of values.

**Example of MongoDB document:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6b764d95d5d00337ce4a61"),
    "city" : "Berlin",
    "courses" : [ 
        {
            "course_date_start" : "2019-09-26",
            "course_date_end" : "2019-09-27",
            "course_price" : "2750",
            "course_trainer" : "Nux Company",
            "date_added" : "2019-09-01 07:42:05"
        }, 
        {
            "course_date_start" : "2019-09-26",
            "course_date_end" : "2019-09-27",
            "course_price" : "2750",
            "course_trainer" : "Nux Company",
            "date_added" : "2019-09-01 07:42:05"
        }, 
        {
            "course_date_start" : "2019-09-26",
            "course_date_end" : "2019-09-27",
            "course_price" : "2750",
            "course_trainer" : "Nux Company",
            "date_added" : "2019-09-01 07:42:05"
        }, 
        {
            "course_date_start" : "2019-09-26",
            "course_date_end" : "2019-09-27",
            "course_price" : "2750",
            "course_trainer" : "Nux Company",
            "date_added" : "2019-09-01 07:42:05"
        }, 
        {
            "course_date_start" : "2019-09-26",
            "course_date_end" : "2019-09-27",
            "course_price" : "2750",
            "course_trainer" : "Nux Company",
            "date_added" : "2019-09-01 07:42:05"
        }, 
        {
            "course_date_start" : "2019-09-26",
            "course_date_end" : "2019-09-27",
            "course_price" : "2750",
            "course_trainer" : "Nux Company",
            "date_added" : "2019-09-01 07:42:05"
        }
    ]
}
```

**My route for "/course"**

```
// Get all courses in the db
coursesRoutes.route('/courses').get(function(req, res, next) {
    courses.find(function(err, course) {
        if (err) {
            return next(new Error(err));
        }
        if (course) {
            console.log(course);
            // console.log(util.inspect(JSON.stringify(course), true, 10))
        }
    });

    res.json(courses);
});
```

**I have tried the following codes for my model:**

```
// Define collection and schema for todo item
var course = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        course_date_start: String,
        course_date_end: String,
        course_price: String,
        course_trainer: String,
        date_added: String,
    }
);

var courses = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        _id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true
        },
        city: {
            type: String
        },
        courses: [course],
        child: course
    },
    {
        collection: 'courses'
    }
);
```

And the following

```
var courses = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        _id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true
        },
        city: {
            type: String
        },
        courses: [{
            course_date_start: String,
            course_date_end: String,
            course_price: String,
            course_trainer: String,
            date_added: String,
        }]
    },
    {
        collection: 'courses'
    }
);
```

**My "wrong" console log output when hitting endpoint localhost/courses as it is now:**

```
  {
    _id: 5d6b764d95d5d00337ce4a61,
    city: 'Berlin',
    courses: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
```

**Expected console log output:**

```
  {
    _id: 5d6b764d95d5d00337ce4a61,
    city: 'Berlin',
    courses: [{
            "course_date_start" : "2019-09-26",
            "course_date_end" : "2019-09-27",
            "course_price" : "2750",
            "course_trainer" : "Nux Company",
            "date_added" : "2019-09-01 07:42:05"
        }, 
        {
            "course_date_start" : "2019-09-26",
            "course_date_end" : "2019-09-27",
            "course_price" : "2750",
            "course_trainer" : "Nux Company",
            "date_added" : "2019-09-01 07:42:05"
        }, 
        {
            "course_date_start" : "2019-09-26",
            "course_date_end" : "2019-09-27",
            "course_price" : "2750",
            "course_trainer" : "Nux Company",
            "date_added" : "2019-09-01 07:42:05"
        }, 
        {
            "course_date_start" : "2019-09-26",
            "course_date_end" : "2019-09-27",
            "course_price" : "2750",
            "course_trainer" : "Nux Company",
            "date_added" : "2019-09-01 07:42:05"
        }, 
        {
            "course_date_start" : "2019-09-26",
            "course_date_end" : "2019-09-27",
            "course_price" : "2750",
            "course_trainer" : "Nux Company",
            "date_added" : "2019-09-01 07:42:05"
        }, 
        {
            "course_date_start" : "2019-09-26",
            "course_date_end" : "2019-09-27",
            "course_price" : "2750",
            "course_trainer" : "Nux Company",
            "date_added" : "2019-09-01 07:42:05"
        }]
  }
```